# Adding custom headers using SMTPMessage class in java

Tags: java, api, smtp

I am trying to fetch e-mail delivery status logs using the events-API provided by Pepipost.
To do this, I first add X-APIHeader, which acts as a unique identifier, corresponding to every e-mail. Then I try to fetch the logs corresponding to every e-mail using the [events-API](https://emaildev.netcorecloud.com/email-api/events-api/logs).

Following is the code that I use to add X-APIheader:-
[image: Code used to send e-mail]

Though the e-mail is successfully received by the recipient, I am unable to access the event logs corresponding to each X-APIHEADER using the [events-API](https://emaildev.netcorecloud.com/email-api/events-api/logs). Also, the events-API works perfectly fine when the X-APIHEADER parameter is removed.

Is this the correct way to add X-API Header using java?

Comment: If you remove the X-APIHEADER parameter, do the responses that you get back from the API have this "xapiheader": "someValueHere" ?

Comment: @SusanMustafa, when the "X-APIHEADER" parameter is removed I get "" (an empty string) corresponding to xapiheader and the remaining response values as per the [events-api](https://emaildev.netcorecloud.com/email-api/events-api/logs).

Comment: ok, lets ask a few more questions.   What version of events-api are you using?  Can you please show how you are sending an EMAIL using events-api?

Comment: @SusanMustafa, I am using v5.1. I am not using event-API to send e-mail. E-mails are sent through SMTP as shown in the problem description. Events-API is only used to fetch event-related logs after the e-mails are sent.

Comment: I dont know..in this case I suggest you do some debugging.

Like at the exact line before sending the SMTP message, check that your HEADER is there.

Then when you do GET /events, check if you have any value inside the xapiheader variable inside the JSON response.   If it is still not there, then the HEADER is being removed for a reason...
Also, are you passing the character limits? It is supposed to be max 255 chars.

https://emaildocs.netcorecloud.com/docs/how-to-pass-unique-arguments-in-each-smtp-email

Comment: @SusanMustafa Yes, I am abiding by the passing limits, but still getting an empty string in x-apiheader.